# What is the meaning of $\mathbb F_p$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Is $\mathbb F_p$ the set of all non-zero elements of $\mathbb Z_p$?

Also I have  a confusion in the number of elements of $(\mathbb F_p)^3=\mathbb F_p \oplus \mathbb F_p\oplus\mathbb F_p$. What will be the number of elements of this set.

Please someone help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I assume that $p$ is a prime number.

Then $\mathbb F_p$ and $\mathbb Z_p$ both denote the set of classes of integers mod $p$.

The notation $\mathbb F_p$ is typically used when the emphasis is on the fact that it is a field: $\mathbb F_p$ is the finite field with $p$ elements.

The underlying set in $(\mathbb F_p)^3=\mathbb F_p \oplus \mathbb F_p\oplus\mathbb F_p$ is the Cartesian product of three copies of $\mathbb F_p$. Now consider this: if $A$ is a set with $n$ elements, how many elements are there in the set $A \times A \times A$ ?

Comment: $p$ must be prime, or at the very least, a power of a prime. But then you would usually use $\Bbb F_{p^n}$.

Comment: You would not use $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. You can't take the direct sum of fields and get another field (assuming you define multiplication component-wise, which is implied with the use of $\oplus$). $\mathbb F_p \oplus \mathbb F_p\oplus\mathbb F_p$ is only a ring, not a field, while $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ designates the (unique) finite field with $p^n$ elements. (You have to do a bunch of work with irreducible polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$ to show that $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ exists and is unique (up to field isomorphism)).